# Bootstrap GRID layout on Desktop and tablet

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid, media-queries

am trying create a grid layout for desktop and tablet .. Am using col-sm for tablet and col-md for desktop .

In desktop it should appear like this : -
[image]

In Tablet it should appear like this :-

[image]

HTML page :-

```
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                   <p>content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                               <p>content</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                       <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                       <p>content</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
```

on the above code ...3rd section and 4th section with be below 2nd section . I want the layout as per the layout given above. How can i implement this . a small template would really help

Answer (score 0):

This should help to get you closer to your desired layout : http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

For your first layout you have an additional row which I have removed here: https://codepen.io/Squeakasaur/pen/wJxzww

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```